# не работает сборка в гифку png-файлов

Tags: ubuntu, bash, анимация, imagemagick, gif

нужно собрать гифку из всех png-файлов и одного конретного jpg-файла, который передается скрипту как первый аргумент. Смена картинки должна происходить через переданное время в секундах.
Не понимаю, что я делаю не так, просто он собирает в итоге только две картинки: исходную и одну png. а если задать время как 0,5, то считает нулем и вообще ничего не делает.

`

```
let " time = $3 * 100 "
echo "$time"
if [[ $# -lt 4 ]]
then var1="$1"
name=${var1%.*}
convert -delay 8 "$1" *.png -loop 0 "$name".gif 2> /dev/null || ( echo error! && exit 1 )
rm *.png
exit 0
fi
echo i convert
convert -delay "$time" -loop 0 "$1" *.png "$4".gif 2> /dev/null || ( echo error! && exit 1 )
echo made
rm *.png`
```

Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, но это мне не помогло. Я уже читала справку по команде convert в imagemagick. 
Более того, я уже писала такой код. И все работало. Но всё слетело, пришлось писать заново. 
И сейчас он соединяет почему-то только 4 картинки: исходную и 3 .png хотя в папке файлов *.png больше. 
Я не понимаю, почему он соединяет не все. Почему такое может быть?